# What's the different between Req/Sec and Requests/sec in wrk result?

Tags: wrk

I am trying [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk), and got these results:

```
wrk -t8 -c200 -d60s --latency http://www.baidu.com
Running 1m test @ http://www.baidu.com
  8 threads and 200 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    15.19ms   36.58ms   1.49s    97.76%
    Req/Sec     1.46k   422.00     2.31k    81.41%
  Latency Distribution
     50%    9.05ms
     75%   12.23ms
     90%   17.17ms
     99%  227.16ms
  22621 requests in 1.00m, 331.43MB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 1632838, write 0, timeout 0
Requests/sec:    376.75
Transfer/sec:      5.52MB
```

I'm confusing by the Req/Sec and Requests/sec values. What's the different between them?

Answer (score 3):

According to the owner of the wrk repo:

> In addition to Latency and Req/Sec being per-thread stats, they're also statistics periodically captured during a benchmarking run. So avg is the average req/sec over the testing interval whereas Requests/sec is simply total requests / total time.

source : https://github.com/wg/wrk/issues/259

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Req/Sec means How many request currently processing at that second;

Requests/sec means (Number of processed requests)/(Seconds used to process these requests);

Comment: do you have some refers link that can help us understand the meanings of those result?